# Strange flickering outline (eevee)

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I am rendering an animation sequence with eevee and I see strange artifacts, as if a flickering outline along the contour of a 3d model (looks like a dotted line), which changes slightly in each frame creating the effect of flickering contours. How can this be fixed? Could it be related to anti-aliasing?

[image]

Comment: Should be z-fighting, try to set up camera clipping more narrow

Comment: @Crantisz It solved it, thank you so much! If you'll add it as an answer I'll be gad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting), try to set up camera clipping more narrow

Comment: Thank you very much!